# What is the least expensive way to get from Dulles airport to Virginia beach, VA

Tags: usa, budget, airport-transfer, iad, virginia

Please help me get from Dulles Airport to Virginia Beach, VA.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review our [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) regarding asking and answering questions since yours is likely to be put on hold as Shopping Question.

Answer (score 4):

Far and away: rent a car.  The rental market in the DC area is very competitive.  Last time I was there, in March, I paid $12 a day for a Hyundai.  Gas in Virginia is as low as $1.30 a gallon.

Don't let them sell you add-ons, that's where they getcha!

Comment: If the OP is under 25, however,  the rental agency is very likely to apply a surcharge. Moreover, if the OP does not already have car insurance, I would strongly recommend at least the liability supplement.

Comment: Do _not_ get the liability waiver.  Your credit-card will probably cover you.  Check ahead, and if it doesn't, get another credit-card.  A single's day waiver can cost more than the entire yearly fee of a credit-card.  Similarly, a brand-new GPS (that you get to keep) is less than five days' rental of one.   Repeat after me: **Do not get add-ons from the rental agencies.**

Comment: Are you confusing the liability supplement for the CDW/LDW? **Most Visa, Mastercard, American Express, and Discover cards issued in the U.S. exclude liability, personal injury, and personal property from rental car coverage.** It is true that for collision and theft coverage, you must decline other coverage. See e.g. [BankRate](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit-cards/does-your-credit-card-insure-a-rental-car-1.aspx), Of course, we don't know if the OP has insurance already, which would make the point moot, also see [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/03/06/travel/rental-car-insurance.html).

Comment: Sorry, yes.  The _waiver_ protects you from anything the rental-car company might charge you -- as would the insurance on your credit-card and your car-insurance. Liability insurance -- it isn't a waiver, regardless of what they call it to dodge insurance regulation -- is a different thing, but I wouldn't worry about: you can only be liable through negligent action on your own part.  A car thief or a drunk driver can make you liable for damage to your car.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Washington-Dulles-Airport-IAD/Virginia-Beach), which is often useful for this type of query.  The cheapest itinerary they show is:

- DC Metro (buses & trains) from Dulles to Union Station
- MegaBus from Union Station to Hampton, changing buses in Richmond, and
- Hampton Roads Transit from Hampton to Virginia Beach, transferring in Norfolk.

The MegaBus will cost about $30 for both buses (fares vary depending on the time of day, but this was the cheapest I saw);  the DC Metro will cost $7–$9 depending on the itinerary and the time of day;  and the Hampton Transit will cost you $3.50 ($1.75 per ride).  So the total cost is about $40–$45 one way.

Note that there appears to only be one bus a day from Richmond to Hampton, leaving at 12:55 PM;  give MegaBus's schedule, you'll have to be at DC Union Station by 10 AM to catch it.

Comment: Good point;  that'll probably drive the total price to $40-$45.  I'll correct the post.

Comment: Heads up: The train drops you off in a not-fun part of town. If you can drive, it'd be quicker and let you get a better lunch/dinner.